# Get arity of a function

Tags: javascript, function, lua, arguments, arity

I'm a JavaScript developer who's learning Lua. I'm stuck with a problem of getting a function's arity in the Lua language.

In JavaScript, it's simple:

```js
function test (a, b) {}
console.log(test.length) // 2
```

How is it possible to do it this easily in Lua?

```lua
function test (a, b) end
print(#test) -- gives an error..
```

Comment: In the interest of avoiding the XY problem can you also provide some context of what you're trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is possible only through the `debug` library, but it is possible.

```
print(debug.getinfo(test, 'u').nparams) -- number of args
print(debug.getinfo(test, 'u').isvararg) -- can take variable number of args?
```

Please see [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_Debug) and [here](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-debug.getinfo) for more information.

---

**Edit**: Just in case you wanted to play with some *black magic...*

```
debug.setmetatable(function() end, {
    __len = function(self)
        -- TODO: handle isvararg in some way
        return debug.getinfo(self, 'u').nparams
    end
})
```

This will make it possible to use the `#` length operator on functions and provide a JavaScript-esque feel. Note however that this will likely only work in Lua 5.2 and above.

Comment: @Kosmetika I've edited my answer with a trick that you might like. Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: i'm using lua 5.1, but I'll try

Comment: There are two special considerations: 1) You can call a function as a method, which adds 1 to the number of parameters (the `self` parameter), and 2) The last format parameter might be `...`, which is a list of an indeterminate number of parameters.